# Angular 2 http post to .Net Core Web Api 500 error

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am sending a post request from angular 2 http to the Web Api and i get the 500 error. I know its internal server error, so that i have some mistake when reciveing the request. But i cant figure it out.

**Page Component**

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserInformation } from '../../providers/user-information';
import { Employee } from './bruker';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-account-creation',
  templateUrl: 'account-creation.html',
  providers: [UserInformation]
})

export class AccountCreationPage implements OnInit {

  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, private userInformation: UserInformation, private _fb: FormBuilder) {

  this.userInformation = userInformation;

}

   public myForm: FormGroup;
   bruker: Employee;



  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


     // the short way
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({          
            Employee: this._fb.group({
                EmployeeID: ['', <any>Validators.required],
                FirstName: [],
                LastName: []               
            })
        });

     this.userInformation.getlogin().subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Task Complete'));
  }

  onSubmit(model: Employee) {

     console.log(model);

    var x = this.userInformation.createuser(model).subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Post Complete'));

  }



}
```

**Service**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response , Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Employee } from '../pages/account-creation/bruker';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserInformation {

     private Url = 'http://localhost:63817/api/Bruker/';  // URL to web API
     headers: Headers;
     options: RequestOptions;

      constructor(private http: Http) {

      }

      createuser(bruker: Employee): Observable<Response>{

       console.log(JSON.stringify(bruker));



            let bodyString = JSON.stringify(bruker); // Stringify payload
            // let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
            // let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 


            return this.http.post(this.Url + "NyBruker", bodyString,{headers: this.getHeaders()})
            .map(response => response.json(),
              error => { debugger; });



      }

       private getHeaders(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
      }

    }
```

**Rest API**

```
using Crashy_Backends.Model;
using Crashy_Backends.Services;
using Crashy_Backends.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace Crashy_Backends.Controllers
{

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BrukerController : Controller
    {


        private IBrukerService _BrukerService;

        public BrukerController(IBrukerService BrukerService)
        {
            this._BrukerService = BrukerService;
        }


        [Route("NyBruker")]
        [HttpPost]
        public Employee NyBruker([FromBody]Employee bruker)
        {
            var x = bruker.EmployeeID;
            return bruker;
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: How can i access the Exception ? i am calling the webApi from a external source as i am building a hybrid app with cordova.

Comment: You access the exception in the web api project. You could set a break point in the controller you are calling and take it from there. From the client side you can print the response to the console and see if the exceptions is added in the response which comes with the 500 status.

Comment: I have tried to put a breakpoing in the Post method, but it doesnt reach it. It does however reach the controllers constructor. On the frontend i get the message back 500(Internal Server Error)  . just status: 500, ok:false, statusText"Internal Server Error"

Comment: ok, Have you tried my answer below? In that answer I describe why you don't reach the method in the controller

Comment: Open chrome or whatever you use. Go to network and call webapi service. When it fails you can open it and view your exception. http://image.prntscr.com/image/99b40e86bbb7491db0224e433f0294a0.png

Comment: Thanks i didnt know about that, I do now get Error 415, unsupported Media Type, must be something about the object i send i suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding on information which you provided, from my own experience most likely the problem is in `dependency injection`.
Have you added `IBrukerService` to dependency injection service in `Startup.cs`?
`services.AddTransient<IBrukerService, BrukerService>();`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection

Comment: Yes i have added this line:  services.AddSingleton<IBrukerService, BrukerService>();  I dont know what the difference between the Addsingleton and AddTransient . could it be something with it?

Comment: Remove constructor from `Controller` to make sure, that problem is not in DI

Comment: Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they are requested  and then every subsequent request will use the same instance. Don't use Singleton for your services. There is great documentation about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the content type header of the request to application/json
2. Ensure your Employee class definitions match

Pretty sure #1 will fix your problem though. :)

Try this:

```
return new Headers({ "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "Content-Type": 'application/json' });
```

Comment: I do think so too. but i have currently this method private getHeaders(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
      } and its called from inside the post method. i am not sure how to declare it correctly , i have also tried this  let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); then send headers as a parameter

Comment: it seems like it didnt help much , but the problem should be something about this . i get this respons in the console. OPTIONS http://localhost:63817/api/Bruker/NyBruker 415 (Unsupported Media Type) and XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:63817/api/Bruker/NyBruker. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 415